# Unzip git tree object

Tags: git

I've written a small groovy utility that can unzip git blob objects and it works, I can see the content of the blobs. The same works for the commits.

The problem is in trees. When I unpack them, I get:
`tree 29100644 a�⛲��CK�)�wZ���S�`. As you can see after the object size it's impossible to read the content. It looks like this content is kept in a different format.

Here is my code:

```
   ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
   InflaterOutputStream byteWriter = new InflaterOutputStream(result)
   byteWriter.write(new File(input).bytes)
   byteWriter.close()
   println result
```

Tried similar things in Ruby and the result was the same. So I think the problem is in the format of the file which is not Zlibbed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

But the tree content isn't meant to be a readable string, if I follow the article "[Git tree objects, how are they stored?](http://smalltalkthoughts.blogspot.fr/2010/03/git-tree-objects-how-are-they-stored.html)":

> The general format is:
>
> - First 4 bytes declaring the object type. In our case, those four bytes are “tree”, ASCII-encoded.
> - Then comes a space,
> - and then the entries, separated by nothing.
>
> The exact format is the following. All capital letters are “non-terminals” that I’ll explain shortly.

```
tree ZN(A FNS)*
```

> where:
>
> - `N` is the NUL character
> - `Z` is the size of the object in bytes
> - `A` is the unix access code, ASCII encoded, for example> 100644 for a vanilla file.
> - `F` is the filename, (I’m not sure about the encoding. It’s definitely ASCII-compatible), NUL-terminated.

```
S is the 20 byte SHA hash of the entry pointed to, 20 bytes long.
```

> Here’s an example.
>   Say we have a directory with two files, called `test` and `test2`. The SHA of the directory is `f0e12ff4a9a6ba281d57c7467df585b1249f0fa5`. You can see the SHA-hashes of the entries in the output of

```
$ git cat-file -p f0e12ff4a9a6ba281d57c7467df585b1249f0fa5
100644 blob 9033296159b99df844df0d5740fc8ea1d2572a84    test
100644 blob a7f8d9e5dcf3a68fdd2bfb727cde12029875260b    test2
```

[image: tree]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction. I couldn't figure out how that SHA1 is encoded into 20 bytes, have found the material here: http://git.rsbx.net/Documents/Git_Data_Formats.txt but the language is too complicated there and it looks like the algorithm is not that simple. Another alternative to see how it works is JGit sources: https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/ but also not very readable.

Comment: An easy way to get the 20-byte output of a hex-encoded SHA1 is to feed it to `xxd -r -p`.